# Batch files: Build a string across multiple lines WITHOUT actually resulting in a multiline string?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I am using a CLI and passing a switch and argument like below where the argument is enclosed in `"` and contains a series of sub-arguments (expressions) separated by a `;`:

```
-switch "a long expression; another long expression; yet another; and hey one more"
```

What I'd like to do is something like this where I can construct the string across multiple lines without actually passing a multi-line string to the EXE:

```
-switch "very long arg; ^
another long arg; ^
yet another; 
and another"
```

Even though that's multiple lines, I'd still be passing a single-line string line the one above.

Update: As I was typing this, I just discovered a sort of hack to get this to work:

```
set myswitch=a long expression; ^
another long expression; ^
yet another; ^
and hey one more
-switch "%myswitch%"
```

It works, but I'd like a more inline approach as demonstrated in my earlier example. Anyway to achieve this in Windows 7 batch files? (inb4 you need to upgrade to Windows 10)

Comment: You need to upgrade to Windows 10, regardless of this question. You can get a key for a few dollars. There is unfortunately no simple answer to this in BATCH, regardless of your windows version. The best way is with cancelled-expansion quotes `!="!^` at the end of your line. Since `="` cannot exist as a variable name, it expands into nothingness. so you could have `echo "This is a !="!^<insert line break here can't really do it in a comment>test of multiline"` It's not clean, it's not simple, but it will work without provided unexpected output due to some character combinations.

Comment: You're worried about it being "in-line" yet you want line-breaks...?  Seems counter-intuitive. :) Just use the variable as you describe, that's your best bet.

Comment: You may want to review the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843711/im-passing-a-multi-line-text-as-argument-which-will-be-saved-in-a-variable-and-t/42879148#42879148).

Comment: @T3RR0R How does that help me? The answer is explaining how to generate an actual multi-line string from a single-line parameter. I am wanting to do sort of the OPPOSITE of that.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin perhaps you should consider updating the question to be clearer regarding which earlier example you are referring to.

Comment: @T3RR0R All you need to do is read the question itself: "Build a string across multiple lines WITHOUT actually resulting in a multiline string?" Besides, there was only one other example prior to the one I was referencing. Not sure how you misread it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not: `set "myswitch=strings"`
`set "myswitch=%var% more strings"`

---

> How does this help me build my command line string across multiple lines with less unwieldy syntax than my "hacked" version in my OP? – oscilatingcretin 7 mins ago

- well, see for yourself which one is more readable.

---

```
set "myswitch=a long expression; "
set "myswitch=%myswitch% another long expression; "
set "myswitch=%myswitch% yet another; and hey one more"

exec -switch %myswitch%
```

---

```
set myswitch=a long expression; ^
another long expression; ^
yet another; ^
and hey one more
-switch "%myswitch%"
```

Comment: How does this help me build my command line string across multiple lines with less unwieldy syntax than my "hacked" version in my OP?

Comment: For use `^` this need 1 space before `^` e no character/space after..

Comment: Re: your edit, I think my version is far cleaner and readable. It's something I can type out in a very fluid sequence of keystrokes without littering it with quotes and variable names. Sorry, but I think the method you proposed is quite tedious to type out and very difficult to look at, let alone read.

Answer (score 1):

Something you may find easier to maintain given your previous comments.

```bat
@ECHO on
rem demo def ! prior to enabling expansion if required in Args strings
Set "Ex=^^^!"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%= [ Paramater list for ... ] =% For %%L in (
"Arg 1 !Ex!"
"Arg 2"
"Arg 3"
"Arg 4"
"Arg 5"
"Arg 6"
"Arg 7"
)Do For /F "Delims=" %%v in ("%%~L")do If not "!Switch!" == "" (Set "Switch=!Switch! %%~v;") Else (Set "Switch=%%~v;")
Set "Switch=-switch "!Switch:~,-1!""
Echo/!Switch!
Endlocal
```